# Books or articles on derivative-free optimization

Tags: optimization, book-recommendation

What are good books/articles you would recommend on/for the topic?

I am supposed to write a seminar paper about the topic, and I would appreciate any books or articles that would introduce me to the topic, from where I could continue writing on my own. So far, I've only found two papers and one of which is computer-science-oriented, and other is from Stanford and only discusses the topic. I appreciate any help.

P.S. the seminar paper should contain from fifteen up to twenty pages, or even more.

P.P.S. it seams as I should start learning Russian, for only Russians delve into these areas.

Comment: Have you looked into [Introduction to Derivative-Free Optimization](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718768?mobileUi=0)? I think it's considered the canonical introductory text for this subject.

Comment: Thank you. I will take look at it. It's, indeed, mind-boggling that everyone reports book-recommendation questions as "off-topic" although I've postulated my question just as stackexchange requires me to. I admit that I had not elaborated my reasons in the question itself, but that's what comments are for (apart from commenting about the solutions). I would explain reasons of my question and reasons why some answers do not satisfy my needs. E.g. the answer below doesn't satisfy my needs for it is mainly focused on CS and the recommended book is poorly covering the topic and focused on general.

Comment: But, hey, It's simpler to say that the question, which doesn't have an apparent solution, is off topic, then let someone get points for providing a good recommendation. I've seen same over and over again. It's fine to ask for "Number theory" or "Enumerative combinatorics" or "Calculus 1" book recommendations just by writing it and not providing anything else, but when someone asks for book recommendations on a "deeper" topic or even articles, it's not for the site and not for mathoverflow either. Pity. Just pity. I am not glad I have to write paper about the topic either, but... not my choice.

Comment: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/ was solution to my problems. Thank you Russians for helping me and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You could start [here](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/pns.html). The site helps you choose an optimization algorithm according to problem type. One of the problem types listed is "derivative free" optimization. There are many references.

Also, bear in mind that some optimization packages that require derivatives also include utilities for estimating these. The donlp2 package does this, for example.

For theoretical aspects, you could start with [this book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf).

Comment: I am more interested in books and articles about it, than software, for I am supposed to write a (seminar) paper about the topic. Something like a graduate/master thesis work, just without postulating anything (or if I am able to, I am aloud to do that). I am supposed to "investigate" it and learn about it on my own, just without using the Wikipedia (professor doesn't like it). Should I add it in the description? Thank you anyway.

Comment: I know nothing about the subject. It is my assignment to research it and write a paper on it. I know that most of these topics are being covered in post-graduate program, but I am still pre-graduate. Why am I studying it that way - I don't know. The theoretical mathematics program at my University requires it that way. I've found two research papers on Google but both are lacking the firm mathematical writing, while one is computer science oriented.